# Where did a few reputation points come from?

Tags: support, reputation

- I started with 1 point.
- Then I got 10 points from successfully asking a good question.
- That makes 11.
- I've got 15 points.
- The [rep. graph](https://superuser.com/users/19032?tab=reputationhistory#sort-top) shows nothing else.
- Where the extra 4 points come from?
- The FAQ doesn't talk about that.

I'm glad I got those points of course, but it would help to know how I did it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've accepted 2 answers - you get 2 points per acceptance.

(It's unfortunate that it isn't mentioned in the FAQ as far as I can see.)

Comment: Thank you!

I'd consider it a bug in the FAQs, since this is really the kind of thing a FAQ should mention.

Can we assume an admin will read here and fix it, or what are we supposed to do?

Comment: It is mentioned: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work-on-stack-overflow/7238#7238

Comment: it is NOT mentioned in the static FAQ linked at the beginning of every page (I would have linked it but there is the "one link per post" limit) http://superuser.com/faq

Comment: (I meant "at the top of every page")

Answer (score 0):

In this case, Jon Skeet is right.

There's also another way for a low-rep user to get two extra points, though: if you're at 1 point and someone downvotes you then takes it back, the system refunds you two points even though you didn't lose them in the first place.

I've demonstrated the latter case here. Notice that you now have 13 rep even though you've only been upvoted once.

Comment: actually no, it didn't work. I had 11.

maybe it was only a visualization bug on your side (i.e. it shows you I have more points but I didn't really have them)?

Comment: That's because someone else downvoted you. Check your rep history: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/139415?tab=reputationhistory#sort-top

Comment: I don't understand: that page doesn't show any downvote for me. Just a +10 points for a post.
http://img5.imagebanana.com/view/0mrw6cr2/rephistorywtf.png